# Yii2: Which is best suited: basic or advanced template?

Tags: templates, content-management-system, yii2

I'm getting into Yii 2.0 nut and bolts (basic template) and I'm wondering whether advanced template would be best suited for the following projects:

1. Single web site with CMS.
2. Small intranet site with a couple of DB applications with user authentication.

I was planning to develop both of them with a basic template but I would like to know the thoughts of some Yii2 guru.

Comment: I had a similar situation and decided to go with two independent yii instances. The main questions are if there many common functions as authentication, admin-processes, etc, AND the security issues. Why expose the intranet site to the internet? You need full blown security that maybe is not required inside a company intranet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Yii2 Guru but i prefer advanced template because the frontend application is correctly separed from the backend application, eventually with common part in a specified common area.
Is a more professional and complete scaffolding.
And more there is a complete user authentication module by default.